# Is there something like filters in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to run this same code for several mailers in an ActionMailer class. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the shared code in a module. Include that module in each of the mailer classes.